# runtime error : cordova-not-available 'ionic native' 3 to operate CRUD data by using SQLite

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

[I'm trying to operate CRUD data by using SQLite in ionic 3, but it is not work cordova to be available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m411.png)

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to describe more detail. Please describe some code where error is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** run `Cordova plugins` on the `browser`. So you need to use the `device` for that.

You can use below `CLI` to run on the `Android device`

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```